# When using the dotvvm visual studio add in (1.1.90 on VS 2017) I can't edit dothtml/dotmaster files any more

Tags: dotvvm

I'm using the Visual Studio DotVVM addin version 1.1.90 with VS 2017 15.5.6.  When I try to edit a dothtml or dot.master file I get a message box from Visual Studio "The operation could not be completed."  How do I overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Please update to VS 2017 15.6 - there were breaking changes in some Visual Studio assemblies.